# Change which schema is accessed by default

Tags: c#, sql-server, schema

I have a database that has been transfered from another server and has the schema `careinflg`. However my C#.net web application looks for objects with the schema `dbo`. Without manually altering every statement in my application is there anyway to point at `careinflg` by default?

I would prefer to do this in the C# layer if possible as the database is on a development server where it would be unwise to alter to the user properties themselves - but I can if there isn't another way.

Answer (score 0):

When creating, altering and referencing objects, [you should *always* specify the schema, regardless of whether you are using `dbo` or any other schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

You can probably change the way your app currently behaves by changing the default schema for that user:

```
USE your_db;
GO

ALTER USER app_user_name
  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = careinflg; -- this is a terribly unreadable name, btw
```

But this is not a ***fix*** and may have other undesired consequences (for example, when your application creates objects). You need to make a conscious effort to always use two-part names for objects.